# Python - save images to folder after requests

Tags: python, image, python-requests

I have this function that fecthes a bunch of images:

```
def get_player_images_with_api():

    url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=274&altIds=true&page={page}&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=274'
    img_url = 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/{player_id}.png'
    headers = {'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com'}

    page=0
    while True:
        try:
            data = requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).json()

            for player in data['content']:
                print('{:<50} {}'.format(player['name']['display'], img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta'])))
            sleep(2)
            page+=1
        except:
            break
```

---

How do I dinamically save each image on a 'path/to/image' folder with `player['name'].png` format?

Comment: What are you having trouble with?  Creating a path? Creating a filename? Saving a file?

Comment: @wwii all of the above

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here you go :)

```
import requests
from time import sleep
import urllib.request


def get_player_images_with_api():

    url = 'https://footballapi.pulselive.com/football/players?pageSize=30&compSeasons=274&altIds=true&page={page}&type=player&id=-1&compSeasonId=274'
    img_url = 'https://resources.premierleague.com/premierleague/photos/players/250x250/{player_id}.png'
    headers = {'Origin': 'https://www.premierleague.com'}

    page = 0
    while True:
        try:
            data = requests.get(url.format(page=page), headers=headers).json()

            for player in data['content']:
                print('{:<50} {}'.format(
                    player['name']['display'],
                    img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta'])))
                urllib.request.urlretrieve(
                    img_url.format(player_id=player['altIds']['opta']),
                    player['name']['display'] + ".png")

            sleep(2)
            page += 1
        except:
            break
```

Comment: in `urllib.request.urlretrieve(url, path)` is the syntax of downloading the file which is currently set as `player['name']['display'] + ".png"`